# Loop through all input values

Tags: php

**Problem**

So my problem is that I have some PHP code that goes to the db and gets student data. Then the program outputs the student info onto the screen. The info is put inside an `input`, because the user will have the ability to edit the info. When the user edits the info and clicks on `Update`, I need the info to get updated on the db. My issue is that I don't how I would loop through all the inputs.

**PHP Code - When user clicks `Update`**

```
foreach ($_POST as $data) {
    echo $data . "<br>";
}
```

**PHP Code - Allow user to edit**

```
<form action="server/edit/students.php" method="post">

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Student ID</th>
                            <th>Firstname</th>
                            <th>Lastname</th>
                            <th>Teacher's Firstname</th>
                            <th>Teacher's Lastname</th>
                        </tr>

                        <?php

                            // get student info
                            $getStudent = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM students");
                            $getStudent->execute();
                            $getStudent = $getStudent->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                            foreach ($getStudent as $student) {
                                $studentID = $student['studentID'];
                                $firstname = $student['firstname'];
                                $lastname = $student['lastname'];
                                $teacherID = $student['teacherID'];
                                $getTeacher = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM teachers
                                                            WHERE teacherID = :teacherID");

                                $getTeacher->execute(array(
                                    "teacherID" => $teacherID
                                ));

                                $getTeacher = $getTeacher->fetchAll();

                                foreach ($getTeacher as $teacher) {
                                    $teacherFirstname = $teacher['firstname'];
                                    $teacherLastname = $teacher['lastname'];

                                    echo "
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><input type='text' value='$studentID'></td>
                                            <td><input type='text' value='$firstname'></td>
                                            <td><input type='text' value='$lastname'></td>
                                            <td><input type='text' value='$teacherFirstname'></td>
                                            <td><input type='text' value='$teacherLastname'></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    ";
                                }

                            }

                         ?>
                    </table>

                    <button type="submit" name="update">Update</button>

                </form>
```

Comment: First off, I don't see any form tags. I guess you just have omitted that? Another thing, you need to add `name`-attributes to your input fields or they won't be posted.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: I would also recommend you to use `JOIN` to get the teacher in your first query instead of calling the database again on each iteration.

Comment: That looks fine, then it's just the `name` attribute that's missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I did was that I used a variable to keep track of the rows of the data.

Code

```
<?php

                            // get student info
                            $getStudent = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY studentID");
                            $getStudent->execute();
                            $getStudent = $getStudent->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                            $value = 0; // counts rows

                            // loop through each student
                            foreach ($getStudent as $student) {
                                $studentID = $student['studentID'];
                                $firstname = $student['firstname'];
                                $lastname = $student['lastname'];
                                $teacherID = $student['teacherID'];

                                // get teacher
                                $getTeacher = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM teachers
                                                            WHERE teacherID = :teacherID");

                                $getTeacher->execute(array(
                                    "teacherID" => $teacherID
                                ));

                                $getTeacher = $getTeacher->fetchAll();

                                // loop through each teacher
                                foreach ($getTeacher as $teacher) {
                                    $teacherFirstname = $teacher['firstname'];
                                    $teacherLastname = $teacher['lastname'];

                                    // output data
                                    echo "
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><input type='text' name='studentID-$value' value='$studentID'></td>
                                            <td><input type='text' name='firstname-$value' value='$firstname'></td>
                                            <td><input type='text' name='lastname-$value' value='$lastname'></td>
                                            <td><input type='text' name='teacherFirst-$value' value='$teacherFirstname'></td>
                                            <td><input type='text' name='teacherLast-$value' value='$teacherLastname'></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    ";
                                }

                                // add to row
                                $value += 1;

                            }

                         ?>
```